# publishing and/or sharing a Flash-created game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have completed building a number of games, using Flash and as3, that I want to a) publish on my Web site, and b) share with others by giving them the games on a thumb drive. I suspect this is a no-brainer kind of question, but I still need help. Is there an easy-to-describe way to do this, or can someone point me to a book, manual, web page, whatever, that will explain it step-by-step?
Thanks ver much!y

Comment: Just publish the Flash games through the "Publish" menu. Upload those files. Then put those files on a thumb drive. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Publish normally using the Flash(SWF) and HTML Wrapper options selected. you will be left with a .swf and .html file which you can upload to your server. Copy both the .html and the .swf and your friends can open them through either the html file or the .swf file.